# Centered image in a DIV not responding to variable height and width

Tags: html, css

I am using this code to center an image in a 100% DIV.

```css
    #mainlog{width:100%;margin-top:15px; height:40%;background-image:url("../images/mbg.png");border-width:0px 0px 5px 0px;border-style:solid; border-color:#f28438}
    #mainlog a{position: relative;left: 50%;float: left;}
    #mainlog img{position: relative;left: -50%;float: left;}
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
    <div id="mainlog">
    <a href="index.php"><img src="images/logo.png" height="100%" width="" alt="Escener Technologies"/></a></div>
```

So what the actual problem is:
You can see here http://m.escener.com/
The center image is not stretching to 100% height of the external DIV. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your image height is of `200px` and the div height is`40%` so your image are not going to take that in a larger screen.

Try to set a fixed height to your div

```
#mainlog { 
  height:200px;
}
```

**Edit**

Now i see what the problem is; you're ussing `float:left` for the `a` and the `img` tags. With this you can resolve your problem:

1. Remove the `float` and `left` properties for the `a and img`.
2. Add to your `#mainlog` container `text-align:center` on the CSS.
3. Add to your `#mainlog a` `display:inline-block` on the CSS.

Those lines will center your img and make it fits the container.

Comment: Actually I cannot set it, the difference in resolutions in mobiles is quite high, so I need to make sure the main logo takes at least 40% of the screen. Imagine I set it to 200px and the height of the mobile is 1920px, it will look bad isn't it?

Comment: i do those changes with the f12 inspector and it works for me if you want make a fiddle with a little part and i can fix it for you